# Can I simulate swarm of heterogeneous robots using gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo can simulate populations of robots. I am looking for 100 robots for my simulation. ARGOS simulator claims that Gazebo slows down (simulation time increases) as the robot population increases by few dozens. Did anyone tried simulating more than 100 robots using ROS-Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16852/can-i-simulate-swarm-of-heterogeneous-robots-using-gazebo?/) by [aakash](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3643/aakash/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are many factors that influence the speed of simulation. Simulating many simple robots can be faster than simulating a single complex one, for example. It all depends on the models used, how the physics parameters are tuned, and the speed of the computer running the simulation.

Here's an example of 50 planes flying in simulation, each model has only a few joints, and there aren't many contacts being calculated. All robots were controlled using ROS and Ardupilot.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zKDdAw609Y

Here is an example with ground vehicles, I believe there were around 300 of them. Note how the simulated time is 4 times faster than real time, even with all these contacts being calculated.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuI1l-cxXWQ

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aakash](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3643/aakash/) on 2017-07-25**:
Hi Louise. Thank you for the answer and showing examples.